# ajax not loading content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a button for increasing the quantity

```
<input name="quantity-"'.$item_id.'" " id="quantity-'.$item_id.' " type="text" value="' . $quantity . '" />

$increase = '1';

<input name="increase-' . $item_id . '" id="increase-' . $item_id . '" type="button" value="+" onClick="cart_change_quantity('.$item_id .','.$quantity.','.$increase.')" />
```

the function:

```
function cart_change_quantity( item_id, quantity, mod ) {
$.ajax({
    url: 'functions/product-change-quantity.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        item_id:            item_id,
        quantity:           quantity, 
        mod:                mod
    },
    success: function(response) {
        if ( response.search('success') != -1 ) {
            var felbontva = response.split('__'), 
                new_quantity = felbontva[1];

            $('#quantity-' + item_id).val( new_quantity );
        }

        else {
            alert( 'An error occured while trying to update your order.' );
        }
    }
});
```

}

and the product-change-quantity.php:

```
$item_id = $_GET["item_id"];
$quantity = $_GET["quantity"];
$mod= $_GET["mod"];

    if ( $mod == '1' ) { $new_quantity = (int)$quantity + 1; }


    echo 'success__' . $new_quantity;
```

it's just not doing anything. I would like to increase the quantity of a product with that button and later i would like to do more things in the background without refreshing the page so that's why i choosed ajax
Thank you!

Comment: You should post more of the html/php mix because it's pretty unreadable as is.

Comment: What does your favorite developer console say? Is the request going through? What are the variables?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of  script functions/product-change-quantity.php?

Comment: what does your log say? trying debugging it by adding some logs and using Firebug.

Comment: If you use the developer tools in your browser you will be able to see any script failures and also network traffic (requests and responses). This should help track down what's going wrong.

Comment: @artsylar I tired to debug with Firebug but everything seems to be fine

$('#quantity-' + item_id).val( new_quantity );  in this line of the script : new_quantity variable gets the value so I think the product-change-quantity.php and the rest of the code should be fine. 

Somehow the input field with the id="quantity-'.$item_id.'" doesn't changes it's value

Comment: so you mean that it was able to get the new quantity but this line "$('#quantity-' + item_id).val( new_quantity );" just doesn't work?

Comment: by running this "$('#quantity-' + item_id)" at the console, does it give you the correct element? (replace the value of the item_id with valid item id). if it doesn't then the element id doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source codes you posted above, you're accessing an input element which is not in your html file. If you can notice that in HTML, you have added space after the item id for the input element's ID. While on your javascript, you didn't add space after item id when you are trying to access the same element although I think it is better if you don't put spaces in your ID.

[HTML]

```
<input name="quantity-"'.$item_id.'" " id="quantity-'.$item_id.' " type="text" value="' . $quantity . '" />
```

[Javascript]

```
$('#quantity-' + item_id).val( new_quantity );
```